# jQuery, animate scroll to top, after it keeps throwing me to the top

Tags: jquery

So with jQuery I made a div, on which you click and it brings you to the top of the page, but then when you want to scroll back down, it keep throwing you to the top. Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#div
{

    background: url(slike/vrh.png) no-repeat;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 93%;
    right: 1%;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(window).scroll(function()  {

  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0)  {

      $("#naVrh").show();
      $("#naVrh").click(function()
      {
           $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0})
      });

  } 
  else
       $("#naVrh").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If your div has an ID of `#div`, why are you targeting `#naVrh` in your javascript ?

Also, binding a certain function to an event is something that we usually try to do only once, and whenever that event occurs the function will be executed.

You are binding the click event inside the scroll event, so that everytime a scroll happens you bind the click event, or in other words when a user touches the mousewheel you bind the click event a couple of hundred times, which is a really bad idea for obvious reasons.

Try something like :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle($(window).scrollTop() > 0);
});

$("#mydiv").on('click', function() {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop : 0}, 1000);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc2Lv/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-top/
See there for the correct syntax

Comment: Your .click handler on line 6 should not be nested in your main scroll function. If you take this outside the function it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#naVrh").unbind("click").click(myHandler);
```

I think you call the event multiple times. Check your code.